# desktop motherboard sometime boot but sometime jusr turn on and automatic off

Tags: motherboard

I have one ibm rev 1.5 motherboard when i turn on with 20 pin Atx power supply and 4 pin vrm supply( 12 volt) then its turn on but when it will shutdown and again i am going to start then just cpu fan start and automatic turn off within second. when i left for one days again start then works fine.

i also observed that without  4 pin vrm supply( 12 volt) i starts motherboard cpu fan always works. so i am confused why its sometimes runs and sometimes not starting please guide me .

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some hardware problem. Check if capacitors on your motherboard is blown (just google "blown capacitors" and see images) - it's most common problem in my opinion.